# Combine multiple columns filtering code into one in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have writen code to filter multiple columns of a dataframe `df`:

```
df = df[df['type'].astype(str).str.contains("new")]
df = df[df['industry'].astype(str).str.contains("business|office")]
df = df[(df['year'] >= 2020)]
df = df[(df['area'] == 0)|(df['area'] >= 30000)]
```

Now I try to combine them into one line with the following code:

```
df = df[
        df['type'].astype(str).str.contains("new") &
        df['industry'].astype(str).str.contains("business|office") &
        (df['year'] >= 2020) &
        (df['area'] == 0)|(df['area'] >= 30000)
        ]
```

But it seems not working (which means the result is not same as the one from the code on the top), how could combine them correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to fix brackets, do:

```
df[
    (df['type'].astype(str).str.contains("new")) &
    (df['industry'].astype(str).str.contains("business|office")) &
    (df['year'] >= 2020) &
    ((df['area'] == 0)|(df['area'] >= 30000))
  ]
```

Comment: It's very weird, I have added brackets, but still when filter line by line, I get `761` rows, all in one line, I get `11703`. :(

Comment: probably you are overwriting the `df` object with filter and using it again for filter, may be? instead of `df` call the filtered df as `df2`